# Task Manager - Powerhshell not launching MS Access

Tags: powershell, ms-access, scheduled-tasks

I have come across a very strange situation and I have not a clue as to why this bug is occuring.

In short, I have a powershell script that if I run manually works 100%
I have set this as a scheduled task in Windows Task Manager and the event launches, runs the SQL element of the powershell script so I know that the issue doesn't exist there.  However, within the powershell code I have it open a specific MS-Access database and this is not working.

shorter version, - Works when not automated, automation works but not MS-Access

I am confused, I have included the code can anyone see anything untoward?

```
$NewFile = '\\Operations Database\Compliance\CancelledLimitOrders\LIOAnalysis.csv'

$ComplianceSQL = @"
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED

DECLARE @startdate CHAR(8)
DECLARE @finaldate CHAR(8)

SELECT @startdate=CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE(),112), -- get date is editable in the negative figure to provide date range for SQL

@finaldate=CONVERT(CHAR(8),GETDATE()+7,112)

select LIOORDERREF, 
        lioclientcode, 
        liodatetimeinput, 
        liosecurityid,      
        CAST(LIOPRICE1 AS MONEY) AS PRICE1,
        CAST(LIOPRICE2 AS MONEY) AS PRICE2,
        CAST(lioexpiryperiod AS FLOAT) AS EXPIRYDAYS,
        lioexpirydatetime,
        liolastupdated,
        liodatetimeoflaststatus,
        liofailurecount,
        liotransactiontype, 
        liobidprice1,
        liobidprice2,
        liobidprice3,
        lioaskprice1,
        lioaskprice2,
        lioaskprice3,
        CAST(lioordercashamount AS FLOAT) AS LIOCASHAMOUNT,
        LIOSTOCKSYMBOL,
        CASE    WHEN liosecurityexchange = 'XLON' THEN LTRIM(RTRIM(liostocksymbol)) + '.L'
                ELSE liostocksymbol
                END AS STOCKAPI,
        liocurrency,
        lioquoteprovider,
        liosecurityexchange,
        CASE    WHEN lioparenttype = 'NULL' THEN 'UNKNOWN' + '-' + LIOPARENTTYPE
                WHEN lioparenttype = '' THEN 'UNKNOWN' + '-' + LIOPARENTTYPE
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'BO' THEN 'BULK ORDER'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'DB' THEN 'BUY DEAL AT BEST'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'DS' THEN 'SELL DEAL AT BEST'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'LB' THEN 'LIMIT BUY'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'LS' THEN 'LIMIT SELL'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'PL' THEN 'UNKNOWN' + '-' + LIOPARENTTYPE
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'RB' THEN 'RISING BUY'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'RT' THEN 'UNKNOWN' + '-' + LIOPARENTTYPE
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'SL' THEN 'STOP LOSS'
                WHEN LIOPARENTTYPE = 'SO' THEN 'SELL ORDER'
                WHEN lioparenttype = 'TS' THEN 'UNKNOWN' + '-' + LIOPARENTTYPE
                ELSE 'UNKNOWN' + '-' + LIOPARENTTYPE
                END AS PARENTTYPE
from xtlimitorder
where left(liolastupdated,8) = @StartDate
and left(lioorderref,2) not like 'PP'
and liostatus = 'c'--
"@

##Development Notes## 

## PS Script to run once every 5 minutes
## PS will download CSV of newly cancelled trades
## On download MS-Access Utilised to 'append data' to daily trades table

#####################
## - CREDENTIALS - ##
#####################

$MISA = 'xxxxxxxx'
$MISB = 'xxxxxxxx'
$userName = 'xxxxxxxxx'
$PassWord='xxxxxxxxxxx'
$DB = 'xxxxxxxxx'
$timeout=0

###### - StopWatch - ######

$timeout2 = new-timespan -Minutes 5
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()

## CREATE MIS CREDENTIALS ##
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connection Timeout=0")
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$MISA;Initial Catalog=$DB;
Initial Catalog=$DB;User ID=$userName;Password=$PassWord;"

## - Runs Script from Set Location

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout;
$SqlCMD.CommandText = $ComplianceSQL;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

## - Extract Data and build sql data object

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet);
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];

$DSETCOUNT = $DataSetTable.Rows.Count
IF($DSETCOUNT -GT 0){
ECHO "AA" 

}
else {
echo "NULL NULL NULL"
$SqlConnection.Close()

## CREATE MIS CREDENTIALS ##
$SqlConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Connection Timeout=0")
$SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=$MISb;Initial Catalog=$DB;
Initial Catalog=$DB;User ID=$userName;Password=$PassWord;"

## - Runs Script from Set Location

$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand;
$SqlCmd.CommandTimeout=$timeout;
$SqlCMD.CommandText = $SECTABLEQUERY;
$SqlCmd.Connection = $SqlConnection;

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter;
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd;
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet;
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet); 
$DataSetTable = $DataSet.Tables["Table"];

$DSETCOUNT = $DataSetTable.Rows.Count
IF($DSETCOUNT -GT 0){
echo "A"

}
else {
echo "NULL NULL NULL"
$SqlConnection.Close()

}

$SqlConnection.Close()

}

#Finally Write the Data to the Table

$DataSet.Tables["Table"] | Export-Csv $NewFile -NoTypeINformation

#################################################
####  Data Download Concluded #############
################################################

### CALL ACCESS FOR FIVE MINUTE UPDATE

$CommandFinal = 'FiveMinuteDataUpdate'

$COMPDB = '\\operations database\compliance\cancelledlimitorders\DBCanxLIO.accdb'
$MSACCESS = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application

### this is not being done in automation, why?

$MSACCESS.OpenCurrentDatabase($COMPDB)
#$MSACCESS.AutomationSecurity = $False
$MSACCESS.Visible = $true
$MSACCESS.DoCmd.OpenForm($CommandFinal)

#$MSACCESS.RunCommand($CommandFinal)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($MSACCESS)

####  Convert xlsx to csv file #### 

$PricesToCSv = '\\Operations Database\Compliance\CancelledLimitOrders\GetCanxPriceTable.xlsx'
$PriceswbCSv = '\\Operations Database\Compliance\CancelledLimitOrders\GetCanxPriceTable.csv'
$Excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$Excel.Visible = $true
$Excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
$PricesToCSVWB = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($PricesToCSv)
$xlcsv = 6
$WorkIt = $PricesToCSVWB.ActiveSheet
$WorkIt.SaveAs($priceswbcsv,$xlcsv)
$Excel.Quit()

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($WorkIt)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xlCsv)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($PricesToCSVWB)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)

######
### CSV Converted
##############################################

Remove-Item '\\operations database\compliance\cancelledlimitorders\array.csv' 

#####
### Iterate through each line of the converted csv and obtain the quote from yahoo finance writing all output to the array.csv file

$GetCanxTradeImport = '\\operations database\compliance\cancelledlimitorders\GetCanxPriceTable.csv' 
$GCTI = Import-Csv $GetCanxTradeImport -Header ('LIOORDERREF',  'lioclientcode',    'liodatetimeinput',     'liosecurityid',    'PRICE1',   'PRICE2',   'EXPIRYDAYS',   'lioexpirydatetime',    'liolastupdated',   'liodatetimeoflaststatus',  'liofailurecount',  'liotransactiontype',   'liobidprice1',     'liobidprice2',     'liobidprice3',     'lioaskprice1',     'lioaskprice2',     'lioaskprice3',     'LIOCASHAMOUNT',    'LIOSTOCKSYMBOL',   'STOCKAPI',     'liocurrency',  'lioquoteprovider',     'liosecurityexchange',  'PARENTTYPE') | SELECT -Skip 1

$IE = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application

ForEach ($StockApi in $GCTI.STOCKAPI) {
$URLA = "http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s="

$URLB = "&f=sc1ll1b2&e=.csv"

#echo $URLA, $StockApi, $URLB

$FUllURL = ($URLA+ $StockApi+ $URLB)

#$IE.navigate2($FUllURL)
#$IE.visible=$true
$OP = '\\operations database\compliance\cancelledlimitorders\array.csv' 

$String = Invoke-RestMethod $FullUrl 

$Data = @()
$Row = New-Object PSObject
$row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "STRING" -Value $String
$Data += $Row
$Data | Export-CSv $OP -NoTypeInformation -Append

###############################################################
###  Has now been written out to array.csv
###############################################################

### Array file requires importing into access to allow updating of files and percentages
}

#### this is not working when automated why??????????????

$Command3 = 'LogicUpdate'

$COMPDB = '\\operations database\compliance\cancelledlimitorders\DBCanxLIO.accdb'
$MSACCESS = New-Object -ComObject Access.Application

$MSACCESS.OpenCurrentDatabase($COMPDB)
#$MSACCESS.AutomationSecurity = $False
$MSACCESS.Visible = $true
$MSACCESS.DoCmd.OpenForm($Command3)
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($MSACCESS)

## Kill resident processes

Stop-Process -Name MSACCESS
Stop-Process -Name iexplore
```

The automated task is simply written as

```
Action = Start a program
Program/Script: = C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
Add arguments (optional) = C:\scripts\ComplianceLimitOrderTestRunTime.ps1
```

I had wondered if this was an execution policy issue but it is set as unrestricted.

I cannot understand why this would work as a manual execution but not as an automated execution, any one shed any light on this?

Comment: Add some logging statements into the script so that you see in which part it fails. For example, use `test-path` to see if file shares are accessible. As a last resort, Sysinterals' Procmon can be used to log all activity and pick the failing operation.

Comment: This is the crux of the matter my friend,  none of it fails... 100% successful except that it is not.

Comment: It could be a (missing) permission issue. When you run it, it's with your user account.

Comment: Why are you using x86 powershell? Also when lauching from the task scheduler for some reason powershell requires you to be more verbose, add `-File` in front of your script argument, you may also want to manually set the execution policy to bypass at launch.

Comment: Whilst both answers are perfectly valid, I have tried both of these variants prior to posting to no joy.   The execution policy is completely unrestricted and so is not at the heart of this glitch.   I am running everything as an administrator so once again this is not a permission issue.   I have a large number of other similar files that utilize all the same logic which run without issue so it has to be something untoward in this particular code set.  Which is not causing an error?  As I say it is very, very odd...